# When the use of the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant is valid

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0

I'm searching oauth2 grant types and I had a doubt.

When the use of the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant valid?

I understand the "security risks it can open", but in the case of the main client is valid?

Ex: Facebook, Twitter, Spotify, etc. do not implement a webview for authentication of their own users in their applications, only for the integration of third parties. They using the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant? Or do they use a different grant type?